# Trouble in Getting Phone Number While Parsing the data inside the script

Tags: javascript, python, web, request, screen-scraping

### Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
my_url='https://www.olx.com.pk/item/oppo-f17-pro8128-iid-1034320813'


with requests.session() as s:
    r=s.get(my_url)
    page_html=bs(r.content,'html.parser')
    safe=page_html.findAll('script')
    print("The Length if Script is {0}:".format(len(safe)))
    for i in safe:
        if "+92" in str(i):
             print(i)
```

### Query

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I Want To Get that phone number that is actually present in windows.state using python script but I donot know how to parse the window.state.Will be very Thankful If you assist me that problem. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: No sir. This is different. what I have now is the script text, when you run that code which I created. Now what I want is that there is field in this script that contains phone number. I want that phone number.

Comment: I just want a python script that will allow me to scrape the phone number that is displayed in the image shown to you. Either you can modify mine one or if you can scrape that in better way I will be very thankful to you

Comment: You can select the seventh ```script``` tag from the code and extract the data you need.

Comment: Actually Having trouble with parsing that phone from that script. That is real problem I am facing. Cannot able to parse that phone number

Comment: I thought of converting that text inside the ```script``` to json and extract the phoneNumber but it is not in json format. I think you need to do a string search and extract the phone number.

Comment: yes  I have tried the same approach as done by you, getting the same error, talking about  converting it into string, as this contains lot of phone number fields which contains null value so I am having trouble getting to the exact phone number that I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, the `window.state` is present inside the 7th `<script>` tag.

I extracted the contents of the script tag and did a string search for `phoneNumber`, found it's index and was able to get the data that you need.

*Extracting data from JSON would be easier but the data isn't in JSON format.*

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.olx.com.pk/item/oppo-f17-pro8128-iid-1034320813'
resp = requests.get(url)

# Convert the response text to HTML soup object
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

# Select the 7th script tag (that is where the data you need is present)
s = soup.findAll('script')[6]

# Extract the contents of script. This will be a string type.
f = s.contents[0]

# Find the index of substring "phoneNumber" - the data that you need.
idx = f.index('phoneNumber')

# Since you need the phone number, use string slicing and extract the data.
print(f[idx-1: idx + 28])
```

```
# Output

"phoneNumber":"+923077250739"
```

Comment: Would you like to give some explanation to this code. if possible from line number 7  to end.

Comment: @ALI I have updated my answer. Please check for explanation.

Comment: perfect Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just have use a simple regex to target the string within the "" following telephoneNumber

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.olx.com.pk/item/oppo-f17-pro8128-iid-1034320813')
print(re.search(r'phoneNumber":"(.*?)"', r.text).group(1))
```